# How does game interface design differ from web design?

Tags: website-design, design, games

I recently saw a similar question on Quora, and was curious about how design focuses in both fields differed?

Bonus points if you can summarize it in a catchy little sentence or something.

Comment: Why do you say that the two interfaces are different? The underlying principles should be the same for the most part - calls to action should be clear and visible, system status should be visible, there should be feedback for user actions, etc.

Comment: This is a fairly broad question, can you narrow the focus for us?  Is there a particular aspect of interface design that you are asking about?

Comment: I think the focus is just UI in general.  I think there is a fundamental difference in UI focus when it comes to games vs. websites, it's just hard for me to summarize it.

Comment: The way I thought about it was game interfaces try to convey a theme of sorts, to engross the player in the game, while websites really want their design to recede, and for the content to stand out.

Comment: While interesting, that is so broad nobody could possibly hope to "answer" the question.  As it stands now, the question is in danger of being closed.  I would recommend narrowing the focus on a particular element or interaction (like menus or affordance for interactivity).

Comment: Here's how I see it.  Web design has fundamental focuses or goals.  I don't think that these goals are the same for game interface design, and I think that this differentiation is interesting.  I'm looking for an "answer" (or maybe at best an "opinion", since UX tends to be strongly opinion-based, unlike most SE sites) that conveys this fundamental difference.

Answer (score 1):

Game interfaces are designed in such a way that :

- They look more catchy and attractive than the normal web interfaces
- They can use somewhat bright colours whereas web interfaces should be of light colours generally.
- they can use many different and excessive images whereas we try to use minimum number of images for websites as they take more time to load.
- the help option is **mostly provided** whereas for websites it is generally not provided (or optional).

Answer (score 1):

Game interfaces will be known for:

- Controlling flows - go back, restart, pause
- Displaying information that is useful/relevant at that particular time
- Visually look more attractive- More graphic - use of icons vs words
- Dynamic - in constant change
- Provide aid to the user if the user is stuck or the user would like to see it

Web interfaces:

- Strict layout - with exceptions of course
- Not designed for users to go back and forth. Actions have flows - start to end
- More text

Answer (score 0):

- game interfaces tend to take a fixed land, keep it and use it, knowing
  that every pixel of it is theirs.  OTOS, web pages get mangled terribly
  all the time.

  I haven't seen many game UIs that can take extensive zooming, window
  resizing, font changing, image blocking....  Whereas with web pages,
  you generally want them to take it and be usable at least.
- On a similar note, when you design a game, you know your interpreter.
  But with web pages, you never know which one of thousands kinds of UAs
  will try to wrap its head around it.